# Python Flask application: include HTML that imports xml file with javascript

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I am trying to create a simple web application using Flask in Python. I want this app to do something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_display_table) example. So I want to import an xml file in the HTML code. When pushing the button, the data of the xml will appear in the page.
My python code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My index.html code is the same as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_display_table) example. I have created a cd_catalog.xml file in my computer. When I run my script, the button does not do anything.

My question is where should I locate the .xml file so that it can be imported to the .html file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `static` directory next to your app module and place file there, public path would be `/static/***.xml`

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files